# Implementar algoritmo evolutivo con tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, redes-neuronales

Estoy intentando implementar un entrenamiento mediante algoritmo evolutivo para una red neuronal usando `tensorflow` y `keras` pero creo que algo no funciona con mi implementación ya que no parece mejora en la tarea.

Actualmente esto utilizando el juego de Tic-Tac-Toe como tarea, esencialmente mi algoritmo hace lo siguiente:

Crea 2 modelos con la misma arquitectura (en mi caso esos modelos constan de un `posisional embedding`, un bloque transformer que costa de una `capa atencional` y una `capa densa` y un `bloque transformer` con una `capa atencional` y una rede de tipo `LSTM`; ambos transformers utilizan un enmascarado causal y sus salidas son normalizada, por ultimo la salida pasa por una capa densa antes de la capa de salida, el tipo de salida es una distribución de probabilidades para la el mejor movimiento).

Una vez los modelos "padres" se crean, éstos se guardan como `archivos .h5`, éstos modelos son hechos predecir con la función `.predict` recibiendo un arreglo unidimensional con los valores de las posiciones del tablero codificado de modo que 0 corresponde a las posiciones del jugador 1 a las vacías y 2 a las posiciones utilizadas por el rival, al final de cada ronda si hay un ganador se guarda sus ajustes con `.save` en un `archivo .h5` y se le ajusta aleatoriamente para crear al rival, el ajuste esta condicionado por una puntuación de castigo que penaliza algunas acciones como elegir una casilla ocupada pero en ultima instancia es un ajuste aleatorio, si empatan o exceden los 20 movimientos ambos modelos se entrenan.

Al principio parece que mejoran pero casi de inmediato se estancan, dejaré el código que estoy utilizando para el ajuste, espero que alguien pueda decirme qué es lo que esta fallando.

Código:

```
def entrenamiento(model, penalization):
    # Inicialización de variables
    aleatory_value = tf.random.normal(shape=(1,), mean=0, stddev=3.0)
    learning_rate = 0.025
    if penalization <= 1:
        learning_rate=0.0025
        aleatory_value = tf.random.normal(shape=(1,), mean=0, stddev=1.0)
    if penalization >= 2:
        learning_rate=0.4
        aleatory_value = tf.random.normal(shape=(1,), mean=0, stddev=3.0)
      # Genera un valor aleatorio decimal entre -3.0 y 3.0 con 4 decimales de precisión
    penalty = tf.cast(penalization, tf.float32)  # Convertir la penalización a float32
    for layer in model.layers:
        if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Dense):
            for neuron in layer.weights:
                current_weight = neuron.numpy()
                adjusted_weight = current_weight * (1 - learning_rate * penalty) + learning_rate * aleatory_value
                neuron.assign(adjusted_weight)
    model.save("model1.h5")
```

No estoy seguro de si este método funciona realmente para algo ya que yo la construí desde 0, y consideren que para la tarea real es imposible conseguir un set de datos etiquetados.

Comment: Ok ya vi lo que pasaba, mi probabilidad de mutación es el 100% por lo que mi población se desestabiliza y tengo 1 o 2 medio decentes y luego todo se rompe